# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'GatherV2' with these attrs.

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, onnx

We are trying to feed an image into our tensorflow model but we keep getting this error:

[ERROR Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YRjL.png)

[ERROR Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmPNj.png)

We used pytorch initially, converted it into an ONNX model, and then to a tensorflow model to be used in Android Studio. We are able to load the model successfully, but after that we run into errors.

Thanks in advance to those that respond!

Answer (score 0):

@AEye Alliance I was getting the same issue while using older version of tensor flow lib for android i.e. compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.5.0' I replaced it with compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.10.0' because 'GatherV2' is available in the updated lib. Please let me know if it fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild tensorflow_inference_android library with 
--copt=-D__ANDROID_TYPES_FULL__ . This would enable it to work on int64 ops. But it would be much slower.